# dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) does not load image

Tags: ios, uitableview, dispatch-async

i am trying to load and display an image then display to to the tableview cell, the image is a link from google. i tried to used `dispatch_async` for easy loading but it does not load all the images.

Heres a part of my code:

```
-(void) buildCellView: (NSArray *) data andIndex: (NSInteger) index{
NSDictionary *comment = [data objectAtIndex:index];
cell.backgroundColor = [BaseView colorWithHexString:@"f3f3f3"];
commentsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
commentUsersImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 8, 28, 28)];
if ([comment valueForKeyPath:@"image_url"] !=nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){
        NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[comment valueForKeyPath:@"image_url"]];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] ;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //                commentUsersImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [[self commentUsersImg] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
        });
    });

}
commentUsersImg.layer.cornerRadius = 14;
commentUsersImg.clipsToBounds = YES;
[commentsView addSubview:commentUsersImg];
```

this is what i'm getting:

[image]

and i store my urls in an array, This is a part of my array of arrays:

```
 [dummyData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", @"badge.png",@"Got Strike! at", @"Alex Shin",
                                                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"James", @"30 minutes ago", @"Great Shot!", @"https://c676132.ssl.cf0.rackcdn.com/_84A2468-50cf361795eb2.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Kim", @"10 minutes ago", @"I should have seen it.", @"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tBFQC9y-ZpM/Tmb8DaeYEmI/AAAAAAAAA9M/TahVx2IiQsE/s400/Bowling+and+Best+Bowling+Player+Shalin+Zulkifli+cover.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Matt", @"5 minutes ago", @"Nice", @"http://www.beverlyhillsmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/Ashton-Kutcher-Hollywood-Stars-Rich-and-Famous-Movie-Stars-Star-of-the-Week-Beverly-Hills-Magazine-Hollywood-Magazines--300x336.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]]

                                                           , nil] , nil]

                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo", @"credit",@"credit_label", @"name", @"comments", nil]
                      ]];
```

Comment: have you getting image from the url call ?

Comment: u were getting the data from server,

Comment: yes i am getting the image. but the table view needs to be reload first. before it displays all the images

Comment: Yes you'll have to reload tableview every time image loads. So after you set image to imageview you can reload tableView.

Comment: when i reload the tableview, the app hangs. cause it loads every time. how can i reload the specific cells inside a specific tableview header? found this code but does not work for me: -(void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;